# How to get UIActivityType after selecting some of share type

Tags: ios, swift

I create an app that could share some text, but is there any that i could get whether type or where user choose the destination ?

here some code that i use :

```
let objectsToShare: [String] = [
                        "\(store.name) ",
                        store.url
                    ]
let activityVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
                        activityItems: objectsToShare,
                        applicationActivities: nil
                    )
self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `completionWithItemsHandler` handler on your `UIActivityViewController`, and then check the `activityType`…

```
let objectsToShare = ["\(store.name) ", store.url]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { activityType, completed, _, error in
    guard completed else { return }

    if let error = error {
        // Handle error
        return 
    }

    switch activityType! {  // See UIActivity.ActivityType
    case .saveToCameraRoll:
        //
    case .copyToPasteboard:
        // 
    case etc…
    default:
        // Otherwise check activityType?.rawValue
        // Apple activities begin with "com.apple.UIKit.activity."
        // Others use app specific values
    }
}
present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```